# Повторяющиеся значения в столбце

Tags: python, pandas

Не могу понять как сделать столбец, чтобы в нем последовательно повторялись значения по нарастанию. К примеру длиной 5.
Должно быть вот так:

```
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5 и так далее до конца датасета.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для датафрейма с дефолтным индексом можно попробовать сделать так:

```
df['col'] = ((df.index)%5==0).cumsum()
```

Comment: спасибо, сам бы не догадался

Answer (score 0):

```
period = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['a'] * 15})
df['Col2'] = df.reset_index().index.to_series().mod(period).eq(0).cumsum().shift(periods=period, fill_value=0)
print(df)
```

```
   Col1  Col2
0     a     0
1     a     0
2     a     0
3     a     0
4     a     0
5     a     1
6     a     1
7     a     1
8     a     1
9     a     1
10    a     2
11    a     2
12    a     2
13    a     2
14    a     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и просто сгенерить список с запасом и обрезать потом по количеству строк датасета:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [0] * 100})
df['numbers'] = [i for i in range(100) for _ in range(5)][:df.shape[0]]
df
```

Comment: получится 500 значений?

Comment: `[i//5 for i in range(100)]`

Comment: @splash58 А потом обрежутся. Лень считать. )  Ну, так то да, можно и так